# What could be a reason for MySQL stop receiving new connections?

Tags: mysql, connections

I'm running a production MySQL on linux whose max connection is configured to 7000. Among 7000, approximately 3500 connections were used by application, serving user requests.

A malicious user tried to login approximately 1000 times with wrong username and password. All connections were access denied for sure, but at the same time MySQL suddenly stopped receiving new connections, producing "too many connections" error.

What could be a cause of this?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331032/mysql-error-1040-too-many-connection

Comment: Please describe why the app needs so many connections.  Normally a request should release the connection fast enough so that you don't need more than a few hundred connections.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of this query. 
 
    SELECT 'SLEEPING Ram use', 
COUNT(*),SUM(time),SUM(memory_used),SUM(max_memory_used) 
FROM information_schema.processlist 
WHERE 
command="Sleep";   

We will quickly know if your system is not releasing resources.  Please post TEXT of your code responsible for Connect, Process, Close which is probably missing the close when your activity is complete.

Comment: What is the TEXT result of this query?  SELECT @@max_connect_errors;